# Python Selenium can't find element or click element

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, selenium, xpath

So I am trying to make my first Instagram bot and I've got the driver to open Instagram. But I can't make my script enter anything or click the username or password boxes.

So now my question is: Why doesn't my script enter anything or (when using **.click()**) clicks the password/username boxes.

```py
class instaBot():
    def __init__(self, username, password):

         self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/blaze/PycharmProjects/InstagramBot/Drivers/chromedriver")
         self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")
         time.sleep(5)
         loginbox = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name = 'username']")
         loginbox.send_keys(username)
         time.sleep(1)
         loginbox2 = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name = 'password']")
         loginbox2.send_keys(password)

instaBot('Code', 'Passerwoee')
```

Elements:

```html
<input aria-label="Phone number, username, or email" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" name="username" type="text" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" value=""/>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `find_elements` while finding the element, `find_elements` return the list of the element, you need to use `find_element` to fetch the element and then you need to operate on it.
You can do it like:

```
 loginbox = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name = 'username']")
 loginbox.send_keys(username)
 time.sleep(1)
 loginbox2 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name = 'password']")
 loginbox2.send_keys(password)
```

Comment: Thought I had "element" in singular... now i works perfectly! Thanks, much appreciated!